# htaccess redirect everything on domain to a single page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to replace an entire website with a single landing page on a different domain. So all of the following domains:

```
example.com
www.example.com
example.com/page-1
example.com/sub/page-2.html
```

should redirect to:

```
new-domain.com/landing-page
```

**Currently**, I'm using the following .htaccess file (no other content in the file):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/landing-page/ [R=301,L]
```

**Additional details:**

- I'm set up on a GoDaddy Deluxe linux hosting package.
- `example.com` is the "primary" domain of the package, not an addon domain. So by default it directs to the root of the my server space (this .htaccess file is in the root).
- I do have several other addon domains, so redirecting all traffic to the server is not an option.
- `new-domain.com` is hosted on the same server space as an addon domain.

**The problem** I'm running into is that `example.com` is redirecting to `new-domain.com` - not `new-domain.com/landing-page`. All other example URLs listed above redirect as intended.

Any ideas why the non-www domain base wont redirect to the subpage?

Comment: Yep; everything redirects except plain `example.com` (with or without trailing slash). Which of course is basically the most important one.

Comment: To clarify, `example.com` is redirecting to `new-domain.com`, but not the intended `new-domain.com/landing-page`

Answer (score 1):

It seems it was a caching issue. Tried it in FireFox and the redirect works correctly in all cases. Went back to Chrome, cleared cache and it worked as well.

Apparently, .htaccess 301 redirects may be cashed.